# Mongoose aggregation $match distinct based on another field?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection like this:

```
[
  {
    "ticketNumber" : "00001",
    "version" : "0"
  },
  {
    "ticketNumber" : "00001",
    "version" : "1"
  },
  {
    "ticketNumber" : "00001",
    "version" : "2"
  },
  {
    "ticketNumber" : "00002",
    "version" : "0"
  },
  {
    "ticketNumber" : "00003",
    "version" : "0"
  },
  {
    "ticketNumber" : "00003",
    "version" : "1"
  }
]
```

The model has additional attributes that I'll be using in a later aggregation pipe. I first need to filter in a way so it returns the tickets based on the distinct ticketNumber and the newest version:

```
[
  {
    "ticketNumber" : "00001",
    "version" : "2"
  },
  {
    "ticketNumber" : "00002",
    "version" : "0"
  },
  {
    "ticketNumber" : "00003",
    "version" : "1"
  }
]
```

Not sure if this is do-able somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do this with the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/). It's a simple [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) operation using the [**`$max`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) operator on your "version":

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$ticketNumber",
        "version":  { "$max": "$version" }
])
```

It would be better if "version" was not a string, but it is still valid since even as a numeric string it is still lexical. But "10" is not lexically greater than "2". So beware of that.

Comment: Thanks, got it working using $max as per your suggestion. Had to include $sort on version prior to $group, and $first inside $group to bring back other attributes for ticket. Hard to wrap my head around it coming from conventional SQL!

Comment: @PixelSheep Well it's really a one answer per one question concept here, but here's the 2c version. Think aggregation "pipeline" just like the unix pipe "|" operand. Everything that comes out of one end and fed through the "pipe", goes into the next end. Each "stage" in the "pipeline array" is an array member. But doing a `$sort` operation and using `$first` would be excessive here because you only want a singular field. Sorting on values and using grouping operators like `$first` is usually reserved for pulling multiple properties in a "row/document". `$min/$max` are more optimal here.

Comment: Thanks for the additionals. The original model is actually much larger, and contains sub-documents, e.g. 'assignments' attribute on 'ticket' contains an array of sub-documents. I actually tested using $max:assignments under the same $group, and it seems to work fine, but I wasn't sure if this is going to be consistent as how would mongoose know what to look for to determine if the array of assignments are "max"/latest version? That's why I thought I'd use $sort before picking out the first set of assignments (and actually, 'version' can replace to use $first as well in this case).